# Map list to dictionary according to value from other list

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
[0,0,3,3,0,1,1,1,3,3,0,2,0,2,0,0,2,2]
```

and this list:

```
[18,23,56,34,23,67,89,43,12,22,34,21,54,23,67,12,45,67]
```

(their lengths are the same)..I'd like to find a way to generate a dictionary from these lists by using as keys of the dict the values from the first list and as the values of each key the numbers of the second list corresponding to the position of the first list..

So the result would be:

```
dict = {'0': '18,23,23,34,54,67,12', '1':'67,89,43',.........}
```

How can I implement this..any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the "numbers of the second list corresponding to the position of the first list" means.  Can you clarify?

Comment: a combination of `zip` and `defaultdict` should help

Comment: @soulcheck's got the answer but I have a feeling the question still contains insufficient information.  How many of the former lists are there?  Really just one, or one per key in the output `dict`?

Comment: for example, 18 belongs to the key 0 because in the lists they are at the same position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> list1 = [0,0,3,3,0,1,1,1,3,3,0,2,0,2,0,0,2,2]
>>> list2 = [18,23,56,34,23,67,89,43,12,22,34,21,54,23,67,12,45,67]
>>> import collections
>>> result = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
...     result[i].append(j)
...
>>> result
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [18, 23, 23, 34, 54, 67, 12], 1: [67, 89, 43], 2: [21, 23, 45, 67], 3: [56, 34, 12, 22]})
>>> result[0]
[18, 23, 23, 34, 54, 67, 12]
>>> result[1]
[67, 89, 43]
```

To get the data structure as described in your question, you can do:

```
>>> for key, values in result.items():
...     result[str(key)] = ','.join(str(v) for v in values)
```

Comment: maybe even `result[str(key)] = ...` -- probably not what he meant, but that is what he wrote.